# Shiny dashboard - hide menuitem in server generated sidebar UI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a server generated sidebar. After its creation, I want to hide its first element. The observer doing the hiding is executed, however, the menuitem is not hidden. I am trying to figure out, why it does not work. Any thoughts?

PS. The CSS selector appears to be correct, as all works when the UI is not created on the server.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
      uiOutput("sidebar_ui")
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      shinyjs::useShinyjs()
    )
   )


server <- function(session, input, output) 
{ 
  rv <- reactiveValues()

  output$sidebar_ui <- renderUI({
    rv$trigger_sidebar_config <- 0
    cat("\nSidebar create")
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar",
                menuItem("Menu1", tabName = "tab_menu_1"),  # to be hidden
                menuItem("Menu2", tabName = "tab_menu_2") )
  })


  observeEvent(rv$trigger_sidebar_config, {
    cat("\nSidebar config")
    shinyjs::hide(selector = '[data-value="tab_menu_1"]')  # hide menuitem
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The goal is to show/add a `menuItem` during the session? Or why do you want to start it hidden?

Comment: I want to hide it during the session. This is just a stripped down example of a more complex use case.

Comment: Sure, just asking because there is the `renderMenu` function to dynamically add/remove `menuItem`s. You can use `shinyjs::hidden` in your `renderUI` call to start hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `observeEvent` is executed too early because the reactive value `trigger_sidebar_config` is updated during the same [cycle](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/execution-scheduling.html) as `renderUI`. Accordingly shiny tries to hide an UI element which isn't existing yet (you would have to wait for the UI beeing rendered, instead of it's calculation beeing triggered, for this to work).

You can test this e.g. via delaying the execution of `shinyjs::hide` - it works when triggered by an `actionButton` (Please see my below example) or you have a look at the [reactlog](https://rstudio.github.io/reactlog/):

[image: reactlog]
Here you can see, that the observeEvent triggered via `trigger_sidebar_config` finished calculating after 3ms but the sidebar wasn't ready at this time (30ms).

If you want the tab to be hidden on startup you can use `hidden()` in your `renderUI` call (see `Menu3`):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("sidebar_ui")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("hide", "hide tab")
  )
)


server <- function(session, input, output) 
{ 
  rv <- reactiveValues()

  output$sidebar_ui <- renderUI({
    rv$trigger_sidebar_config <- 0
    cat("\nSidebar create")
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar",
                menuItem("Menu1", tabName = "tab_menu_1"),  # to be hidden
                menuItem("Menu2", tabName = "tab_menu_2"),
                shinyjs::hidden(menuItem("Menu3", tabName = "tab_menu_3")))
  })


  observeEvent(input$hide, {
    cat("\nSidebar config")
    shinyjs::hide(selector = '[data-value="tab_menu_1"]')  # hide menuitem
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this context please also see `?renderMenu()`.

Comment: Thanks!. I suspected that execution order was the reason. How Can i find out that it is the case. Could you elaborate a bit? How can one e.g. see that ist the same cycle?